# Access file in weblogic server

Tags: dns, weblogic, directory

Is there a folder in the Domain Directory of Weblogic, where files put inside can be accessed directly from web browser? In other word, I don't have to pack the file in an ear, war file and deploy it to make it accessible? 
Thank you very much
Regards
K.

Answer (score 2):

The [Virtual Directory Mapping](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1039396) feature (that you declare in the `weblogic.xml`) would do the trick:

> Using the virtual directory mapping
>   feature, you can create one directory
>   to serve static files such as images
>   for multiple Web Applications. For
>   example, you would create a mapping
>   similar to the folowing:
>
> ```
> <virtual-directory-mapping>
>   <local-path>c:/usr/gifs</local-path>
>   <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
> </virtual-directory-mapping>
> ```
>
> A request to
>   http://localhost:7001/mywebapp/images/test.gif
>   will cause your WebLogic Server
>   implementation to look for the
>   requested image at:
>   `c:/usr/gifs/images/*`.
>
> This directory must be located in the
>   relative uri, such as
>   "/images/test.gif".